# Plot two point in a 5 dimensional space

Tags: python, matlab, plot, visualization

I have a `5-D` space. I want to point out `2 point ((1, 4, 12, 18, 28) & (1, 4, 128, 128, 128))` in that space. Is it possible to plot a visualization using `MatLab Or Python?` Any kinds of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**For better visualization you can assign any values on those points**

Comment: You want to _plot in 5D space_? Really? I already find it challenging to plot in 3D...

Comment: @LuisMendo You can check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41086-5d-data-visualization-with-matlab)

Comment: That a look at “parallel coordinates”. It’s a visualization method for high-dimensional data.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot visualize a 5-D space, but here is what I do when I have to visualize 4D or 5D data -- I use 2 or 3 coordinates to plot a point, and convert the rest of the coordinates to color/ size variations. Here is a working example in python (Jupyter Lab) with a 3d plot:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['pt1', 'pt2'],'x':[1, 1], 'y':[4, 4], 'z':[12, 128], 'u':[18, 128], 'v':[28, 128]})
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, s = df.u, marker='o', c=df.v, cmap='prism');

for i, txt in enumerate(df_test.index):
    ax.text(df_test.loc[txt, 'x'], df_test.loc[txt, 'y'], df_test.loc[txt, 'z'], txt, color='k')
```

Comment: Thanks, for your effort. But what is `df_test` variable?

Comment: @Phi it is a dataframe that contains the 5D coordinates for the 2 points in the question